# How I can make custom select box with search bar using html css js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i am trying to make a custom select box with search bar using html css and js. once done it didn't work (scroll bar didn't work, and search bar too)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might consider using jQuery UI Autocomplete: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

To display some text when the checkbox is checked:

**HTML:**

```
Checkbox: &lt;input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()"&gt;
&lt;p id="text" style="display:none"&gt;Checkbox is CHECKED!&lt;/p&gt;
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myFunction() {
    // Get the checkbox
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    // Get the output text
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
}}
```